# Extensão do MongoDB não encontrada no PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mongodb

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP 5.6 com Laravel 5.2 utilizando MongoDB.

O problema surgiu quando decidi atualizar meu Mac para o El Captam em uma instalação limpa, pois quando eu instalei o PHP 5.6 com Brew junto com a extensão do MongoDB, a class `\MongoDB` não existe, apesar de aparecer no `phpinfo()` a versão do drive mongo 1.1.6.

O que será que está acontecendo?

Consegui instanciar a classe `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`, mas os comandos são totalmente diferentes da classe que eu utilizava.

Terei de migrar minha aplicação para este novo driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao utilizar o MongoDB com o PHP temos que ter em mente que existem duas versões de drivers.

Temos a extensão `mongo` e a extensão `mongodb`, sendo a segunda a versão mais recente.

O driver que você irá utilizar depende da versão do PHP e do MongoDB que você estiver utilizando.

Veja qual escolher de acordo com as tabelas extraídas da [documentação do MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php):

```
 PHP Driver                 | MongoDB 2.4   | MongoDB 2.6   | MongoDB 3.0   | MongoDB 3.2   
--------------------------  |-------------  |-------------  |-------------  |-------------  
 PHPLIB 1.0 + mongodb-1.1   | X             | X             | X             | X             
 mongodb-1.1                | X             | X             | X             | X             
 mongodb-1.0                | X             | X             | X             |               
 mongo-1.6                  | X             | X             | X             |               
 mongo-1.5                  | X             | X             |               |               

 PHP Driver  | PHP 5.3 | PHP 5.4 | PHP 5.5 | PHP 5.6 | PHP 7.0 | HHVM 3.9 
-------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|----------
 mongodb-1.1 |         | X       | X       | X       | X       | X        
 mongodb-1.0 |         | X       | X       | X       |         | X        
 mongo-1.6   | X       | X       | X       | X       |         |          
 mongo-1.5   | X       | X       | X       | X       |         |
```

No ponto de vista de código, a nova extensão tem um foco maior em operações de baixo nível para comunicação com o MongoDB, tanto que é recomendável utilizá-la em conjunto com o [MongoDB Library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/) para ter uma interface similar ao driver antigo.

> Terei de migrar minha aplicação para este novo driver?

No seu caso, depende da versão do PHP e do MongoDB que você está utilizando.
A última versão do driver antigo suporta até o MongoDB 3.0 e o PHP 5.6. Basta você remover o driver novo e instalar a versão antiga. Dá pra fazer isso usando o [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo).

Caso queira usar a versão mais nova do MongoDB ou o PHP 7, ai você precisar mudar seu código para usar a *library* mais recente.