# Erro "Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found"

Tags: php, mongodb

Na hora da utilização de do **MongoDB**, junto com o **Laravel** ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> FatalErrorException in Client.php line 61: 
>   Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Comment: Você editou o database.php do Laravel ?

Comment: http://haafiz.me/development/using-laravel-with-mongodb

Comment: Ja segui esse tutorial e nada

Comment: Está instalado o Driver no Servidor ?

Comment: Está , mas desconfio que o erro possa ser no servidor , pois o mongo esta como extensão ativa mas não aparece no phpinfo

Answer (score 4):

Atualmente, existem dois drivers do para MongoDB: o [mongo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mongo.php) e o [mongodb](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/set.mongodb.php).

O `mongo` é legado. Já o `mongodb` é mais atual, funciona com versões mais atuais do PHP, além de funcionar com HHVM e outras coisas. Na reescrita do novo driver, entre outras mudanças, todas as classes foram reformuladas e os namespaces mudaram.

Com base no seu erro de `Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found` [é possível inferir](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) que a biblioteca para MongoDB que você está tentando utilizar em conjunto com o Laravel, utiliza a versão mais nova do driver, a `mongodb`.

[A versão mais nova pode ser instalada com o pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb). Após essa instalação, esse erro deverá parar de ocorrer.

Comment: Ela deveria vir com o Módulo Driver na biblioteca instalada pelo composer, como ocorre com Exception e Operation na classe Client. Todos estão no vendor, menos o Driver. O erro é em MongoDB\Driver\Manager dentro da  própria classe. Isso não permite que ela busque alguma coisa no SO, mas sim em seu namespace. Que há um diferença entre legado (mongo) e mongodb,há, mas o problema aí é outro. No meu caso, o meu composer.json está como mongodb/mongodb:1.*, então ele deveria trazer todo o conteúdo, incluindo o namespace Driver. Dando problema em conjunto com a mongo.so, é outra história.

Answer (score 2):

Não é problema no Laravel, é falta do modulo MongoDB no PHP.

> Note que existe duas versões do modulo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143674/3635

Para instalar o modulo do MongoDB você vai precisar:

- php 5.4 ou HHVM 3.9
- libbson e libmongoc (https://github.com/mongodb/libbson)

Instalar por PECL:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

E depois adicione no php.ini isto:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

Se for Windows baixe a versão Thread Safe em http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Extraia o `php_mongodb.dll` e copie na pasta `extensions/` e depois adicione ao php.ini:

```
extension=php_mongodb.dll
```

---

### Baixando o MongoDB do Github

Pode tentar a instalação manual via Git, no entanto será necessário compilar, no entanto é necessário instalar o `phpize` primeiro, se for Debian ou Ubuntu (ou baseado neles) use o comando para PHP5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Se for php7.0, 7.1, 7.2 (e futuros) use:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Ou:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dev
```

Ou:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
```

Então depois de instalar (e tendo instalado o Git) execute os comandos:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
cd mongo-php-driver
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
phpize
./configure
make all -j 5
sudo make install
```

É possível compilar em Windows usando o Visual Studio também, mas é necessário baixar em https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/ o php-devel, por exemplo:

```
php-devel-pack-5.6.37-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-5.6.37-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-5.6.37-Win32-VC11-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-5.6.37-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.0.31-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.0.31-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.0.31-Win32-VC14-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.0.31-Win32-VC14-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.1.21-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.1.21-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.1.21-Win32-VC14-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.1.21-Win32-VC14-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.2.9-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.2.9-nts-Win32-VC15-x86.zip
php-devel-pack-7.2.9-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
php-devel-pack-7.2.9-Win32-VC15-x86.zip
```

Escolha conforme a versão do teu VisualStudio e do teu PHP.

---

### Instanando MongoDB no HHVM

Se estiver usando HHVM então terá que baixar via Git:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hhvm-driver.git
cd mongo-hhvm-driver
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init --recursive
hphpize
cmake .
make configlib
make -j 5
sudo make install
```

Após qualquer um dos processos citados talvez tenha que reiniciar o Apache (ou HHVM)

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.php